# Resolve hostnames with NetBIOS instead of mDNS on Linux

Tags: debian, networking, windows, netbios

Immediately after installing Debian 9 Stretch, the avahi-daemon has already been installed, so it is working to send a ping between Linux with avahi-daemon installed on each of them.

For example, when there is a named 'alice', `$ ping alice.local` returns a normal response.

I want to do the following things:

- I want to resolve names of Windows from Linux, but I do not want to install the Bonjour or something like that on Windows.
- I want to resolve names with NetBIOS (WINS) instead of mDNS.
- I do not want to add a suffix such as `.local` in the name.

So I deleted avahi-daemon and installed winbind.

```
# dpkg --purge avahi-daemon libnss-mdns
# apt-get install winbind libnss-winbind
```

And, added setting to use 'wins' in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`. e.g. `hosts: files dns wins`

With the above setting, `$ ping mywindows` will not respond. However, `$ nmblookup mywindows` can successfully get the IP address.

Previously, when I was using Debian 8 Jessie, it should have been successful, but using Debian 9 Stretch will not be my expectation.

Is there something missing?

Comment: Do you have a WINS server installed somewhere?

Comment: No WINS server. For WINS query recieved by broadcast, each Windows host will return own IP address with UDP/137

Comment: A follow-up: do you have `nmbd` running?

Comment: `winbind` depends on`samba`. Installing `winbind` automatically installs `samba` as well. Therefore, running `apt-get install winbind` installs `nmbd` as well. `ps ax` command showed that `nmbd` is running.

Comment: I suggest using Link-local Multicast Name Resolution (LLMNR) instead of WINS. LLMNR is serverless just like mDNS. In fact, it essentially does what mDNS does, it was just Not Invented Here. Windows hosts talk it without the need to install anything, just make sure the network connection is not set to "public network".

Comment: I found the issue. It may be the same problem. https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=825380